# How do i get NSPopover to be first responder from the NSStatusbar?

Tags: xcode, macos, nspopover

My question is simple and easy; How do i get NSPopover to be first responder from the NSStatusbar?

I'm asking for a short code, not a link to a big XCode-project. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though you've probably solved your question by now, you can do this:

```
[yourPopover becomeFirstResponder];
```

If you want more control, just setup your containing controller for a NSPopoverDelegate.

```
[yourPopOver setDelegate:self]; /* Don't forget including the <NSPopoverDelegate> in your headerfile */
```

Then you can use 5 functions to gain more control over your popover.

```
– popoverShouldClose:
– popoverWillShow:
– popoverDidShow:
– popoverWillClose:
– popoverDidClose:
```